# prove you have found all such functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, maximum-principle, entire-functions, liouville-function

find all possible entire functions f with the property that $|f(z)|\le2|z|+1$ for all $z\in C$. Prove that you have found all such functions.
First of all I am self studying complex analysis so sorry if i am not very precise on thrms or... 
My idea is : since f is entire, then it is analytic in all complex plane.
can I say f is bounded in complex plane? then by liouville's thm or maximum modulus principle claim that f can only be a constant function?
if yes, how should I prove my claim. and how should I prove I have found ALL possible functions f?

Comment: doesn't  $f(z)=z$ satisfy the inequality?

Comment: Do you know about Cauchy estimates? In general given an entire function $|f(z)|<p(|z|)$ you can bound the degree of $f$ by the degree of $p$

Comment: If you prove that the given property implies that f is in your set, then you've proved that your set contains all functions with the given property. But note that $f(z)=z$ has the given property and is not bounded.

Comment: If f is entire then f is analytic at every point. If $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k z^k$, you can consider g defined by $f(z)-a_0=z.g(z)$ and prove that $g$ is bounded.